# EU citizenship. Can she be deported?

Tags: european-union

Based on EU Law only:

A Spanish national, moves to France with his family: his wife, an Italian national, and their children. The husband works for a multi-national corporation and is very well paid. The wife remains at home with the children. They have substantial savings, although they do not have medical insurance in France. The wife always travels back to Italy for medical treatment for her children or herself when required. After 3 years in France, the husband is relocated by his company to India. The wife decides to remain in France with the children who have settled in school. She chooses not to work. She is required to complete some paperwork relating to the children’s schooling and the authorities notice the absence of medical insurance.

Would the wife be deported on the grounds that she does not have medical insurance in the host country and that she is not a worker, even though her children go to school there?

Comment: I am not an expert on France, nor could I find anything specific online. But the EU regulations require either employment or being self-sufficient and other member states have implemented that as meaning you need money *and a health insurance*. There is a good chance France implemented the EU directive the same way. That said, where in France do they live that they travel to Italy every time a kid has the flu or needs a vaccination or just a regular checkup? If they aren't living practically on the border, that seems like child endangerment.

Comment: There are special cases for couples that break up, where one party can remain in the country even though they do not have their own income, but I would still assume they'd need health insurance. Everyone does.

Comment: @nvoigt the requirement to have health insurance is explicitly authorized by the directive.